# Sorting array values to object properties using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have been trying to do the following:

```html
var arr1 = ["A", "B"];

var arr2 = ["A", "B"];

// Where the result should be
var arrayOfObjects = [
  {
    arr1: "A",
    arr2: "A"
  },
  {
    arr1: "B",
    arr2: "B"
  }

];
```

Essentially I would like to sort out the arrays into objects. I don't know how else to explain in words. I could do this the long and hard way through looping. I am used to this kind of programming because I come from a long history of C and C++ programming. I would like some help figuring this out in a cleaner JS way.

Also if anyone can point me to a great reference for being able to solve problems like this in JS. I have tried looking at W3schools and the MDN but not enough examples are shown when looking up useful functions. Or maybe I just suck at reading the docs and would like references that help me to understand the docs.

A more specific example was asked:

```html
var name = ["John", "Adam"];
var age = ["19","31"];

result = {
  {
      name: "John",
      age: "19"
  },
  {
      name: "Adam",
      age: "31"
  },
}
```

Also all arrays are the same length.

Comment: Can you provide a more complex test case? What if they're mismatched like `["A", "D"]` and `["B", "C"]`

Comment: what about arrays with varying lengths?

Comment: In JavaScript it does have a function to sort array containing of just numbers or string, but with objects you will have to write your own object comparer to sort. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript

Comment: Please post the code with looping that you would have written, so that we a) know what it is supposed to do and b) have a baseline example to compare cleanliness.

Comment: @mylee This question has nothing to do with sorting actually

Comment: You're looking for [`zipWith`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=zipWith+[js]) functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Here's an example:

```
const arr1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
const arr2 = ['A', 'B', 'C']

// use the map function on the array with the greater length i.e. arr1
// if length is equal, use either
const arrayOfObjects = arr1.map((element, i) => ({
  arr1: element,
  arr2: (i < arr2.length) ? arr2[i] : null // handle index out of bounds on arr2
}))
```

Process is not really sorting, but mapping an array of strings to an array of objects. 
Personally, I find the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript) the best reference for Javascript.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me figure out my problem.